# Remove one line after TOC title

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there a way to remove a line between the "Content" title and the first chapter of the TOC? 
If that helps, here is my doc's specifics.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, doublespace, openany]{report}

\newpage
\maketitle
\newgeometry{top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1.5in}
\vspace*{-0.9in}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Theoretical Background}
```

[image]

Comment: My problem is that, I don't know what is the specific vspace length that corresponds to one line based on my font size and on the fact that my document is double spaced.

Comment: `tocloft` seems to be the package you should look into, i found out as much with 2 google searches... do your research before asking ;)

Comment: Yes, I already know about this command and it works. But I don't know what is the exact vertical space (pt) I have to remove. How many pt correspond to one line in my case?
    
    \setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{-10pt}

Answer (score 4):

Using the `tocloft` package, you can substract the the equivalent of one line by doing

```
\addtolength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{-\baselineskip}
```

---

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{-\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Theoretical Background} 

\end{document}
```